# How to express Modulo operator constraint in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to state the modulo operation constraint in any open source optimisation modelling language.

How can we state the following constraint : y = x mod 3. Where x, y are integer variables.

Struggling to formulate the above.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to model a modulo with linear constraints?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2513559/82433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y = x mod 3` can be modelled as follows:

```
x = 3b + y
0 <= y <= 2
x, y, b are integers
```

Since y can only take values : `0, 1 or 2`,  `x` can be determined by some unique values of `b` and `y` such that `x = 3b + y`

`b` and `y` are respectively the quotient and remainder of `x mod 3`

*edited : per @reinderien comments*

Comment: Thanks @Reinderien for the feedback. Edited the answer per your callout.